# deployed webapps health in jetty server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jetty

I understand enabling JMX in jetty, we can fetch some information about deployed webapps.

Can Jetty also provide enough information to indicate that a given webapp is up and running, or some metrics that can be considered to identify the state of deployed webapps?

Comment: "Healthy" is an ambiguous term that means too many different things to different people.  Can you modify your question to be more precise about what you are looking for?

Comment: done. thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a Jetty Server Dump.

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-dump-tool.html

This will output the state of all relevant components within Jetty.

This can be accessed via the various "dump" methods on `Server` (choose the one that you want).

You can trigger this Jetty Server Dump within JMX as well.

Alternatively, you can ask each of the deployed webapps their running state.

Use the `org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle` interface, and the `.isRunning()` method.

The `LifeCycle` interface is available on all deployed webapps, even if they are an instance of `WebAppContext` (for war files), or `ServletContextHandler` for manually created webapps, or even `ContextHandler` for "bare metal" handling of requests.